# "Extension with name 'android' does not exist" error when adding Kotlin to Android project

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to add Kotlin to our Android project using [the official Kotlin tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html), Gradle fails launching the error `Extension with name 'android' does not exist`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Android Studio modifies your `build.gradle` adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` above `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`. Just move the Kotlin line below the Android one and Gradle will run smoothly. It should look like this example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: I have this issue while I'm trying to use an external `gradle` by doing `apply(from="$rootDir/common-android.gradle")` in my feature module `build.gradle.kts`

Answer (score 17):

This is the correct order for above extension issue.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Answer (score 6):

with new versions use

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

Comment: That's true. Thanks for the answer :·)

Comment: worked for me in 2022

Answer (score 0):

[image]

New use in `2022`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```